# Get timestamp for the next hour

Tags: time, go, timestamp

How can I get the timestamp of the next hour?

Example: Something expires in 1 hours, so it would be time.Now() plus one hour

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`time.Now().Add(time.Hour)`

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/48KATjPbc-)

Comment: This is certainly a valid answer. It's just succinct because there's little to add beyond a one-line example!

Comment: Thanks, it does the job!